# Why do truffle compile or migrate commands fail silently?

Tags: truffle, contract-deployment, ganache, linux

Truffle v5.0.3 config:

**truffle-config.js**

```
module.exports = {
  // See <http://truffleframework.com/docs/advanced/configuration>
  networks: {
    development: {
      host: "127.0.0.1", //also tried 'localhost', just in case
      port: 7545,
      network_id: "5777"
    }
  }
};
```

Ganache v1.3.0 config[image: ganache gui default settings]

on executing `truffle migrate --reset` or `truffle compile` or `truffle migrate --network development --reset --compile-all --verbose-rpc` happens nothing: no output, no builds. I suppose the same code worked before (with output and builds), however, on the different OS (using Linux Debian at the moment).

What is wrong with the configuration?

Edit:
Ganache logs show there is no connection from truffle during my attempts to compile contracts.

```
[9:09:57 PM] Starting server (version 1.3.0) with initial configuration: {"hostname":"127.0.0.1","port":7545,"network_id":5777,"default_balance_ether":100,"total_accounts":10,"unlocked_accounts":[],"locked":false,"vmErrorsOnRPCResponse":true,"verbose":false,"gasLimit":6721975,"gasPrice":20000000000,"hardfork":"constantinople"}
[9:09:57 PM] Ganache started successfully!
[9:09:57 PM] Waiting for requests...
```

Comment: The configuration seems to be fine, try deleting the `build/` directory in your project. Another thing to check is truffle is correctly installed.

Comment: Log shot ... Is it possible you're running from the wrong folder context? You should be in the project root folder with a sub-folder called `./contracts`.

Comment: @Ismael there is no `/build` dir yet. Truffle seems to be installed correctly globally, it outputs its version and help.

Comment: @RobHitchensB9lab The context is correct. When it's wrong, there is a `Could not find suitable configuration file.` error message.

Comment: @Polyakoff Are you runnig ganache and truffle in the same computer? Did you try in a different computer? Is your project available on github? What does `truffle compile --all` returns? Without more info it can be an issue with truffle installation (try uninstalling a reinstalling), migrations scripts in your project, another problem with your setup.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rolling back truffle to v4.1.13 resolved my issue. I was able to see error messages (`openzeppelin-solidity` was a missing dependency), fix errors and build contracts.